# Passing an ID To a form laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm fairly new to laravel, and all I have to do is pass the id of the currently logged on user with

```
{{ Form::hidden('user_id',   auth()->user()->id ) }}
```

but it's not secured, How can i pass it without people can check it using Dev Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the authenticated user's id within your controller's method instead of passing it to the view. For example, inside your controller:

```
/**
 * Create a new resource.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $formParams = $request->all();
    $formParams['user_id'] = \Auth::id();

    ...
}
```

Comment: How about passing it through an ArticleRequest Requests?

Comment: No problem, there are many different ways to do that with security. IMO my solution isn't the best one, but it is better than sending it through the form.